# Bind a controller $scope to objects in service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I'm creating a multi-step wizard using angularjs.  The steps in the wizard could potentially change by actions the user takes.  I'm storing the steps in a navigation service.  I want the navigation controller to respond to changes in the navigation steps (which occurs in the service).  How do I do this?  The below code does not work.  Also I am using ui-router for the wizard steps, I'm wondering if I'm going about this the wrong way and the steps should be stored in the parent $scope rather than in a service.  But examples I've found online suggest using a service.

Here's a jsfiddle I wrote to exhibit the behavior (http://jsfiddle.net/uLytj/16/)

Wizard Navigation Service:

```
angular.module("myApp").factory("wizardNavigationSvc", [function () {
    var service = {};
    var steps = []
    var currentStep = {};
    var currentStepIndex = 0;

    return {
        init: function() {
            steps = [{ state: "wizard.options", display: "Options", isActive: true, isFirstStep: true },
                     { state: "wizard.newmodel", icon: "glyphicon-plus", otherActions: ["Add Another Model"] },
                     { state: "wizard.other", display: "Other" },
                     { state: "wizard.customer", display: "Customer Info" },
                     { state: "wizard.shipping", display: "Shipping Info" },
                     { state: "wizard.review", display: "Review", isLastStep: true }];
            currentStep = steps[0];
            currentStepIndex = 0;
        },
        steps: steps,
        currentStep: currentStep
    };
}])
```

Wizard Navigation Controller:

```
myApp.controller('wizardNavigationCtrl', ['wizardNavigationSvc', '$scope', '$state', function (wizardNavigationSvc, $scope, $state) {
    wizardNavigationSvc.init();
    $scope.steps = wizardNavigationSvc.steps;
    $scope.currentStep = wizardNavigationSvc.currentStep;
}])
```

Wizard Navigation view:

```
<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs wizard-tabs">
        <li ng-repeat="step in steps"
            ng-class="step.isActive ? 'active': ''">
            <a ui-sref="{{step.state}}">
            <span ng-if="step.icon" class="glyphicon" ng-class="step.icon"></span>
            <span ng-if="!step.icon">{{step.display}}</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/uWdUJ/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413670/watch-a-service-variable-or-broadcast-an-event-with-angularjs

Comment: I edited the controller so that it more closely mirrors that other suggested solution, removed the $watch and just assigned the variable from the service instead.  It still doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: I think it's my wizardNavigationSvc but I can't pinpoint what's wrong.

Comment: when I inspect wizardNavigationSvc.currentStep it is always undefined in my controller, even though I can see it being set from within the service.

Comment: I created a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/uLytj/), can you please help me get this fiddle to work?  Thanks.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uLytj/14/
still not working

Comment: I removed all the extra stuff from the fiddle, this is very, very basic now, and still not working! :( http://jsfiddle.net/uLytj/16/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand why this worked or was needed.  I had to put my scope variables inside the service within another object.  Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uLytj/25/
And here is the applicable code:

```
myApp.service("wizardNavigationSvc", [function () {
    var navigation = {
        steps: [],
        currentStep: {},
        currentStepIndex: 0
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

looking at your jsfiddle, its not defined because the service is not returning anything

Ex: on one of the lines (in your service) you have:

```
steps: steps,
currentStep: currentStep,
```

these should be:

```
steps: function(){return steps),
currentStep: function(){return currentStep},
```

Comment: sorry, forgot they need to be functions, updated above

Comment: I've updated the fiddle, this does not work.. please see the fiddle and the suggested fiddle above (http://jsfiddle.net/uWdUJ/), it does not return a function.

Comment: I removed all the extra stuff from the fiddle, this is very, very basic now, and still not working! :( http://jsfiddle.net/uLytj/16/

Comment: I removed bootstrap as it was showing some kind of error, but here is a working service, not a provider as you were using http://jsfiddle.net/uLytj/19/

Comment: unless you're very well adjusted to angularjs and understand the framework VERY well, don't use providers, they are overkill, so unless you have a very good reason, just use a 'service' or a 'factory'. See the developer guide here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

Comment: It was initially a service, the only reason I changed it was mirror the jsfiddle you posted above.  Your example is not working, the "steps" array and "currentStep" variable are both empty always. :(

Comment: I've made this super-simplified and added a watch for the current index, it's very straight forward, yet still not working.  http://jsfiddle.net/uLytj/23/

Comment: finally got it working!  I had to put the variables within another object in the controller (navigation).  http://jsfiddle.net/uLytj/25/